# Jenkins pipeline environment variable negation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

It's scripted pipeline:

```
stage('check negations') {
    def someVar = false
    println someVar
    println ! someVar

    env.skip = false
    println env.skip
    println ! env.skip
}
```

I expect it gives

```
false
true
false
true
```

but it gives

```
false
true
false
false
```

How?

It works correctly for non-environment variables. It even works correctly when env.skip is set to true. How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

env variables are always strings.
so when you do
`env.skip = false`
env.skip will contain the string "false", which its Boolean value is true.

You can do:

```
env.skip = false
println Boolean.parseBoolean(env.skip)
println ! Boolean.parseBoolean(env.skip)
```

In addition, if this env.skip is a Boolean job parameter, you can access it by
`params.skip`. In this case you will get its Boolean value.